radiobutton appears twice primereact datatable reactjs
Working on primereact datatable checkboxes and radiobuttons, in few environments we deployed the applciation, we can see the radio button or checkboxes appears twice just like below:

I can see some difference on the HTML code generated by primereact library as below

p-hidden-accessible div is missing here on which we can see radio button rings twice
the below one it is working fine.

unable to find how to fix this as even in dev environment (local machine) is working fine
I am using     "primereact": "^10.0.5", version in package.json in all the environments

show us a bit of code if you want help.  minimal-reproducible-example

@sparkJ - Unable to edit and add the code, as everytime, the screenshots are going missing, so let me add the code of primereact radiobutton here  https://primereact.org/radiobutton/

You need to update your theme.  I think you upgraded PrimeReact version without upgrading your theme.  See: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/wiki/Migration-Guide-for-Templates
Your issue is this one: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/6181
Double checkboxes and radiobuttons and it definitely means your theme.css does not match your PrimeReact version.
